# Enable pySpark on Airflow for Docker

Tags: docker, pyspark, airflow

I am running Airflow on Docker using `pucker/docker-airflow` image

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 puckel/docker-airflow webserver
```

How do I make pySpark available?

My goal is to be able to use Spark within my DAG tasks.

Any tip?

Comment: Have you tried installing it with `requirements.txt`? (https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow#install-custom-python-package)

Comment: Yes, it works, I overlooked that, many thanks Cesar

Comment: Great. I added a comment with the instructions from the documentation into this question to have it as a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `requirements.txt`, add all the dependencies in this file and then follow: https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow#install-custom-python-package

```
- Create a file "requirements.txt" with the desired python modules
- Mount this file as a volume -v $(pwd)/requirements.txt:/requirements.txt (or add it as a volume in docker-compose file)
- The entrypoint.sh script execute the pip install command (with --user option)
```